# SharePoint Online - Issue with REST API call on a List exceeded the threshold limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, list-view-threshold, response

I have a List in a SharePoint Online site collection which has exceeded 5000 items. I have indexed the columns that are needed in the REST API filter query during list creation itself.

Below is the Rest API query I use to fetch the data from the list.

```
https://sptenant.sharepoint.com/sites/spfxqaw44/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announcements')/items?$top=4999
&$filter=(Expires ge '2022-12-06T18:30:00.000Z') and (RecordDate le '2022-12-06T18:30:00.000Z') and IsActive eq 1 and WorkflowCompleted eq 1
&$select=Id,Title,Expires,ShortDescription,Created,RecordDate,Attachments,LangTrans&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$orderby=RecordDate desc
```

The above query gave me an error as threshold limit exceeded. So I have created a simple list and made a API call as below,

```
https://sptenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('LoadTestList')/items?$filter=Title ne 'Load Test'&$top=4999
```

Generally the return data count should be 4999 but I am able to get only 4970 items as response data. Also this response count is unpredictable, for some other lists I got response count less than 4000.

Any idea on this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: How many items are in the list when you try this filter: `$filter=Title ne 'Load Test'&$top=4999`?

Comment: The total item count in the list is 5001. Number of items that has title 'Load Test' is 6. As per the query I should get response count as 5001 - 6 = 4995 but I am getting threshold limit error if there are 4995 items. If I am increasing the items that has title 'Load Test' as 7, I am getting proper response and the count is 4994. Why am I getting error for 4995 items. I am confused. And this count 4995 is not same for all the lists, I have another list which gives me throttle error for 4950 and getting proper response for 4949 items.

Answer (score -1):

When we try to access more than 5000 items at a time, which is the default threshold limit, we get an error.

You can run your query multiple times, storing each result.

Please refer: [Resolve threshold issue in SharePoint REST API](https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/resolve-threshold-issue-in-sharepoint-rest-api)

Comment: This is the general practice whenever threshold limit is reached. We have done these already.

Comment: You can edit your very very helpful post by adding those details.